# Why can't I run GUI apps as root: "No protocol specified"?

Tags: debian, x11, kde, gui

I installed Debian onto my machine last night. Now, I don't understand why I can't run GUI apps from a terminal when running as root.

For example:

```
sudo -i
glxgears
```

Generates the following output:

```
No protocol specified
Error: couldn't open display :0
```

But when I first open the terminal I can run `glxgears` from the user account. It's only after I do `sudo -i` that the problem crops up.  This happens for any GUI app that I try to run.

I think it's probably related to X11, but I'm not sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20612084

this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: About Wayland, just in case: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_GUI_applications_as_root#Wayland), ["sudo with graphical apps doesn't work on wayland "](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451).

Comment: @Alexey: The ArchWiki also contains a [workaround using xhost](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root#Using_xhost). I tried running LinSSID and sparrow-wifi on Sway (Wayland) which worked after executing `xhost +si:localuser:root`, discussion [here](https://github.com/ghostop14/sparrow-wifi/issues/34).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Accessing the X server requires two things:

- The `$DISPLAY` variable pointing to the correct display (usually `:0`)
- Proper authentication information

The authentication information can be explicitly specified via `$XAUTHORITY`, and defaults to `~/.Xauthority` otherwise.

If `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` is set for your user, `sudo` will set them for the new shell, too, and everything should work fine.

If they are not set, they will probably default to the wrong values and you cannot start and X applications.

In Debian `$XAUTHORITY` is usually not set explicitly. Just add

```
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```

to your `.bashrc` or explicitly say `XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority sudo ...` and everything should work.

You can also use `xauth list` to check whether proper authentication information are available.

Comment: `xauth info` shows path to authority file

Comment: `xhost +` fixed my problem

Comment: Be aware that `xhost +` completely deactivates authentication and allows everyone to access all application on your screen...

Comment: for debian, do I type the XAUTHORITY export as  root?  because it's not working on deb10?  I login with sudo su

Comment: @marinara use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su -`.

Comment: Now that Debian 10 (Buster) is out, how do you do this with `wayland`?

Comment: `xhost +si:localuser:root` seems to work similar.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18, I had to `export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`

Comment: if anyone came here having issues with xrdp, just keep in mind that only the user you logged in with has the rights to start X apps. so e.g. your default ubuntu user is logged in, you cannot start GUI apps as root user....

Answer (score 37):

I had the same question as you but for a normal user. Let's say I want to start firefox using the user account foo. I'm logged in as bar:

```
[bar@localhost ~]$ sudo -u foo -H firefox
```

Sadly that command failed with the same error as in the question (i.e. no protocol specified & cannot open display)

My solution was to simply add the user foo to the list of authorised access to the X server.

```
xhost si:localuser:foo
```

And that was it, I was then able to launch Firefox (and other X application) using `sudo` and the user foo.

***Background***: On X Window, there is a client/server architecture. When you launch an application you request the X server authorisation to display it. By default once you open a session (you graphically login), you (your user) are obviously allowed to commmunicate with the server and display applications. Other users do not have this permission unless you specify it. `xhost` is a tool to manipulate the list of permissions. The `si` indicates that the rule is server side and it authorise the local user `foo` to display applications. X Window is very powerful in this regard and you can display remote applications locally by playing with the `DISPLAY` environment variable and `xhost` (but not limited to them). In older times, when people typed `xhost +` and implicitely allowed everyone to use their X session, it was possible to display application on their screen for pranks ;-) not so much nowadays as people are less and less using X Window client/server architecture (at least for what I observe in the past 10 yers).

*PS: I did this in order to launch Firefox in a kind of "jail" (to avoid a [vulnerability like for pdf.js](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2015-78/) in the future). But I quickly found out that calling Firefox via sudo won't allow it to access audio nor the video hardware. But there is one guy which explain clearly [how to activate video hardware acceleration and audio when calling Firefox via sudo](https://kparal.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/how-to-run-graphical-applications-with-sudo/). YMMV with these instructions, e.g. I still have a permission denied with audio but video is fine (tested on Fedora 22 with SELinux ON).*

Comment: In my case `foo` was `root`, i.e. I had to run `xhost si:localuser:root` on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Where do you add the `xhost si:localhost<user>` command? If no users are logged on, then no one has an X server available to give permission to.

Comment: @cbcoutinho The above use case is when someone is logged on and wants to run an XWindow application as someone else on the same host. If you explain your use case (what is the problem you would like to solve) then I can potentially help you.

Comment: @Huygens I have a workstation for simulating fluids that is also equipped with a GPU. I render the visualizations with `ParaView`, a program built on `vtk`, usually on the workstation itself. `ParaView` also provides a secure headless client/server rendering model through ssh, which I would like to take advantage of remote instead of using VNC. Without logging into the workstation and executing `xhost`, I can't utilize the GPU. That means that I can't reboot the machine remotely and still have access to the GPU.

Comment: @cbcoutinho X Window is a client server architecture. When you connect via ssh, your local workstation becomes the client X Window. You could use the xhost with unsafe protocols like rlogin but not ssh. You need to instruct ssh to do it for you. Either use the `-X` or (better?) `-Y` flag on ssh, it will do the proper redirection. Of course you then need a local C Server. However with GPU and OpenGL, I am not sure where the rendering/compute happens perhaps it’s on the client side, not the server one. Could be tricky.

Comment: @Huygens thanks for getting back to me. Regarding the rendering, `ParaView` has a server available with an offscreen rendering flag. Adding a dummy user with 'auto login' solved my problem

Comment: logged in as myself (as opposed to root), running `xhost si:localuser:root` worked for me

Answer (score 16):

You can either

Specify the display to be used on the command line, by adding `-display :0.0`

or

Set up the environment variable in root's login script (one of .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile ...).

`export DISPLAY=:0.0`

You can check whether it's set,

```
$ env |grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0.0
```

To open up your display for all users from all hosts as your normal user you can do this with :

`xhost +`

Edit: Thanks and credit to @Toby Speight for his comment below for the more targeted suggestion, instead of opening it up for anybody.

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

Comment: xhost + does work as a temporary measure before going in as sudo

Comment: `xhost +` worked for me too, only that they forgot to mention we should run it from the authorizing user's terminal, not from a terminal under `sudo su`.

Comment: perfect work like boom

Comment: `xhost +si:localuser:root` would be a more targeted approach, better than allowing all users.

Answer (score 6):

Given that you're on Debian, the simple and supported solution is to arrange for `sudo` to copy your X11 authorization credentials.  `pam_xauth` is included in the `libpam-modules` package for exactly this purpose; to use it, you just need to add

```
session  optional  pam_xauth.so
```

to your `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file.  You may also choose to add it to `su`, too.  For full information, consult the `pam_xauth` man page, of course.

Comment: That is the most correct and underrated answer, since it also fixes a lot of other related issues and is a far cleaner solution. Putting `session  optional  pam_xauth.so` to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and `/etc/pam.d/su` do work to launch softwares as root in the meantine `pkexec` (which was meant to replace `gksu` and `gksudo`) get its issues together when everything else said here failed.

Answer (score 3):

What helped me:

1. You can `xauth generate :0 . trusted` on the `user` side, which will generate a new `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1`
2. Check the newly created Key with `xauth list` as `user` and `root` (they should be the same if your `XAUTHORITY` variable is pointing to the same file.
3. Voila, `root` will access any X application from terminal, but only temporarily.

To make it permanent, see @Huygens' answer!

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo` command has a switch to preserve environment variables.

```
 -E, --preserve-env            preserve user environment when running command
```

So that you can run the command with -E switch. Example:

```
sudo -E wireshark
```

If you don't need to run privacy critical applications like web browsers, you will be better off adding -E switch with sudo. We cannot run Chrome or Firefox just by adding *-E* switch. Because many browsers have implemented protection against user space violations. @huygens's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223952/46991) may have insights on this subject.

Note: *Adding -E switch will not help if your user's environment does NOT have* `DISPLAY` *and* `XAUTHORITY` *already set correctly*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I did the following to use sudo:

You can use `sudo` with GUI using the options `-sE`, as follows:

`sudo -sE GUI_CMD`

For example, if you want to run `nemo` as root:

`sudo -sE nemo`

Answer (score -3):

use this command and it will work

```
sudo cp /home/user/.Xauthority .Xauthority
```

Comment: This will give `cp: cannot stat ‘/home/user/.Xauthority’: No such file or directory` on any of the 10+ Debian based machines I have access to.

Comment: This gives a little context (e.g., you silently expect some current directory) and you don't mention side effects like troubles when doing so in multiple X11 instances. I think this way is a bit hacky.