# Difference between 'xhost + ' and 'xhost +SI:localuser:AnotherUser'

Tags: x11, su, xhost

If I do

```
xhost +
>access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
su AnotherUser -c xterm
```

an xterm pops up.
However if I do

```
xhost +SI:localuser:AnotherUser
>localuser:AnotherUser being added to access control list
su AnotherUser -c xterm
```

I got `No protocol specified`, I'd like to understand why it doesn't work.

I am in Debian sid amd64

Comment: Could you [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/224235/edit) your question and add the output of `xhost` after you have added permission for the second user.

Comment: I added the output of `xhost`, which was requested by @XTian, as `>output`,

Comment: Works for me; similar platform.  `su -c xclock` fails before I `xhost +SI:localuser:root` and succeeds afterwards.  Can you show us what your `$DISPLAY` looks like, and also the output of `xhost` with no arguments?

Comment: @TobySpeight: please note that AnotherUser is a user different from root; xhost is issued by root; the output is `access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect` `SI:localuser:root`

Comment: Increase verbosity for X server to understand that better (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1243478#p1243478). 
Here they write that problems may be connected to DISPLAY or XAUTHORITY (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118826/89346).

Comment: `xhost` considered harmful, `xauth` is more secure. You can maybe use it on a secure network, but don't think that restricting to a particular user will make it more secure. It can only stop accidental connection.

Comment: please add output of `echo $DISPLAY`