# Run a program under another user with X server display

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, users, display, user-interface

I want to be able to run (just) a program/few programs under a test user named "test" and at the same time benefit of the GUI of the program.
I need this because I want to be able to save test settings without conflicting with my own settings.
What I found so far is that I can either:

- use `su test` to switch to the user, but then I can not run programs with GUI... they complain about not having a display:

  ```
  No protocol specified
  ```

  ** (gedit:17086): WARNING **: Could not open X display
      No protocol specified

  (gedit:17086): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
- use the `dm-tool switch-to-user test` to actually switch over to that user

Any Idea how I can run programs as another user without having to change users and desktops each time?

Comment: Google and read about X authorization (`xauth`, `.Xauthority`). IIRC Gnome or rather `gdm` botched this at some stage by hardlinking the MIT "cookies", but I don't remember details. So you may have to look closely.

Comment: Please write up your solution and answer your own question, so others with the same problem can profit from your work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution as provided in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223952/166466) answer

All I had to do was run the following command as root:

```
xhost si:localuser:test
```

Apparently this command allows the user to use the display server.

Please edit this answer if you know more about this issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
xhost +localhost
```

then `su test` ..

Comment: I tried it.. it does not work... I get the same error when running gedit