# No protocol specified: Unknown Error couldn't connect to display ":0"

Tags: debian, root, gui, display, xauth

I've installed Debian 8 since a week, but I can not run any graphical application from console with the root user.
Infact, when I run xampp (or any other program) I get the following error

```
root# /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Unknown Error couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

I've googled the error and tried any suggestion, but haven't solved the problem.

This is my Xauthority

```
root# echo $XAUTHORITY
/root/.Xauthority
```

This is my DISPLAY variable

```
root# echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

The strange fact is that with my user (not the root one) I don't have any problem and I can run any graphical application.
The DISPLAY variable is the same of the root one:

```
user# echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

I also tried the suggestions here --> [Why can't I run GUI apps from 'root': “No protocol specified”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/why-cant-i-run-gui-apps-from-root-no-protocol-specified):

```
root# xauth + root
xauth: (argv):1:  unknown command "+"
```

and the command

```
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
```

doesn't have any effects

Comment: Maybe you mean `xhost +` instead of `xauth +`?
Note that `~` is expanded in the home directory... so it depends on how you gain root.

Comment: Thank  you for your comment. I've tried both. Also with "xhost + root" I don't get any results. When I write "xhost + root" with the root user I get the error, meanwhile when I write it with the user I get "root being added to access control list", but nothing happen

Comment: Comment from [one answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118825/66388) of your link: _`xhost +` does work as a temporary measure __before__ going in as `sudo`_. Try this: open a terminal, write `xhost +`, gain the root access `su -`, try to run a graphic program (e.g. `xlogo`)... Sorry I've to go.

Comment: Wow! It worked! Can you explain to me the meaning of the operations? Thank you!

Comment: I've restarted the pc and still the same problem as before. Is there a command to keep the configuration?

Answer (score 4):

I only used `xhost +` then ran `sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run` and it came up for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using the command `su -`.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su)  is the difference between `su -` and `su`

Answer (score 0):

You should properly use the `xhost` command. You could use either `xhost +IP` or `xhost +Username`.

For root user command you need to run is: `xhost +root` or for every user on localhost machine: `xhost +localhost`.

Finally you can run

```
$ xhost +
```

which will remove ACL from `xserver` temporarily.

You could read a manpage on xhost `man xhost` and see that it accepts one argument and you were passing two arguments `+` and `username` instead of 1 argument which is `+username` or `+IP`.