# Open multiple instances of a given application

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I am using Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS 64-bit) with the Gnome desktop environment.

My issue is that in the Activities menu, when searching for and selecting certain softwares (like `Videos`), if an instance of that software is already open, clicking on it won't open a new instance (new window) but will redirect me to the already open one. Right clicking on the icon and selecting "open a new window" does exactly the same.

I'm guessing it is a configuration setting in a a file like `dconf` that screws it up, but can't find where it is and haven't found a single thread describing my issue.

(Interesting to note that, I am able to open a new window of a given application if that one contains an option to open a new Window itself like Firefox or VS Code)

Does anybody know the answer ?

Comment: To be clear: the left-click behaviour is the default for GNOME. However it might be possible to change the behaviour as you prefer.  The "open a new window" not doing what it says, sounds like a bug - but on apps which don't implement "open a new window", it is unlikely that you can change the behaviour.

Comment: I think you might be able to configure it following these instructions : https://askubuntu.com/questions/125243/how-do-i-open-a-new-instance-of-an-application-by-default-in-gnome/770312#770312

Comment: The bug part is fixed in some more recent version of GNOME.  For example, on Fedora 28.  Videos does not let me open more than one window - but once I have opened one Vidoo window, the "New Window" menu item no longer appears :).

Comment: Yeah, my issue was currently for "Videos", I made a mistake (which i'll edit right away), not all applications behave like this. After doing what you linked, I now get the same behavior as when right clicking and selecting "New Window". I see the "buffering" icon for several seconds then nothing. But ok, this is not a bug then thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: Open one instance as admin ( right clic), and another as usual, it helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Gnome Shell, you can simply open a second instance of the application by opening it with:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↵</kbd>

Some application might not support this as they can only work with one instance

Edit:
it seems if the application do not support multiple instance you can run it as a different user. This user will need to have the proper authorization. [All the information here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223952/53092)

Comment: AFAIK `can only work with one instance` limitation is for a user, not display, so run as another user. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/761369/446998

Answer (score 1):

***Found*** : `Videos` doesn't support more than one instance.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik running as other users helps. As superuser just like that: `sudo app &`. As another user `sudo -u username app &` one need to give `username` permission to use X display, e.g. `xhost si:localuser:username` (from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223952/446998).